# Where is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery library defined in .NET Core 2?

Tags: .net-core

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04

I have written an ASP.NET application that is based on .NET core 1.1. This application works as expected. Today, I just upgraded my server to `dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-preview2-006497.` After the upgrade, I ran the following commands in my project directory to make sure everything is up to date:

```
$ dotnet migrate
$ dotnet restore
```

Now, when I run my application and try to navigate to my login page, I get an error "Cannot find compilation library location for package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery."

Wondering how I can fix this. Regards.

Comment: have you updated you app to targeted to .NET Core 2.0 preview and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery dependency in csproj to be [2.0.0-preview2-final](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/2.0.0-preview2-final)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am thinking "dotnet migrate" will automatically do that. Looks like I will need to do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently `dotnet migrate` only migrates a Preview 2 .NET Core project to a .NET Core SDK 1.0 project, you have to manually update your app to targeted to .NET Core 2.0 preview and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery dependency in csproj to be [2.0.0-preview2-final](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/2.0.0-preview2-final) (and the same for other dependencies).